# changing an applications settings on download

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to change an applications settings upon someone downloading it from a website, For example if user a downloaded it using account a from my website it would change a setting to "login a" and if user b downloaded it using account b it would change a setting to "login b", I did search around but couldn't find anything about storing/altering the app config or anything similar

Comment: You could build the login function inside your application? This way you are sure that the user using is an authenticated user

Comment: not really an option to be honest, it would be allot easier to set a string on download, or even make a copy of the file, set a string and offer a unique download link of some sort, It is definitely possible because ScreenConnect seems to work in a similar way

Comment: There are two possible options that I can see - Both involve making a temporary copy of the download to another folder. - One is to include a text file in the download that is dynamically generated with the user's account name. The other - and to me better - would be to have a setting saved in the project settings and dynamically edit the project's .exe.config file before it is downloaded. There are obviously issues with protecting that data - you should probably encrypt it of course.

Comment: the second option sounds like a good solution. The connection string is encrypted when added to the appconfig.